# Maven Picking Wrong maven-release-plugin version during build

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have explicitly specified in the Parent pom.xml to use maven-release-plugin `2.5`, but during maven build it picks version `2.2.2`.

Here's definition

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version> 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Here's the version its picking

```
Downloading: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/*removed*/maven/v1/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.2.2/maven-release-plugin-2.2.2.pom


    <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-source-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <maven.cobertura.datafile>
                        ${basedir}/target/cobertura.ser
                    </maven.cobertura.datafile>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                com/specsavers/**/*Test.class
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <check>
                        <branchRate>85</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>85</lineRate>
                        <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                        <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate>
                        <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate>
                        <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate>
                        <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate>
                    </check>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>true</useProjectReferences>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version> 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<pluginManagement>` section anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I do. Its <build><pluginsManagement><plugins> and then this.

Comment: Can you please show that section?

Comment: Edited in the question.

Comment: Do you have `<profiles>` that possibly specify a different version somewhere? Can you try running `mvn help:effective-pom` which resolves all variables/combinations?

Comment: Why are you using ancient old plugin versions ... ? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ and Java 1.5 ?

Comment: I do have `<profiles>` but its for sonarqube. As I am building it on a Pipeline, its not possible to run mvn commands.

Comment: Its a really old project. And the devs need it to be built in Java 1.5,

Comment: It would be helpful to have a log output and the full pom files and not only parts of it...